# Playing audio file with golang

Tags: go

How one would play audio file in go language?

I have function and want sound to be played as notification when event happens.

I could not find anything about playing sound file in go lang just some web browser based music players but it wasnt helpful too much.

Comment: You probably will need a library, for that, in which case the question would be off topic...

Comment: perhaps there's a go library for SDL...

Comment: There are go Binding for portaudio (https://code.google.com/p/portaudio-go/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the PortAudio Go bindings (`go get github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio`) for this.

You will have to build or install PortAudio on your system. Consult http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/tutorial_start.html for this.

A complete example for playing back a sound file is located at https://github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio/blob/master/examples/play.go

Comment: Is there any library for playing audio files that fully written in Go?

Answer (score 4):

If it's an MP3 file, you can use [go-mp3](https://github.com/hajimehoshi/go-mp3) Library. go-mp3 is popular library to play MP3; MP3 decoder is in pure Go.

Or this one, https://github.com/faiface/beep. Beep uses go-mp3 under the hood

Comment: how can i use go-mp3 library to run mp3? any snippet?

Comment: `go-mp3` is not pure go as it requires `Oto` - which requires `CGO_ENABLED=1` (atleast on arm).
Oto github issue: https://github.com/hajimehoshi/oto/issues/118

Comment: @Zeeshan what does pure mean in the go sense? only stdlib?